# Domain object string field auto trimming

Tags: grails, grails-orm

After update from Grails 2.2.3 to Grails 2.3.5 (groovy 2.0.8->2.1.9) I found strange behavior
Domain object:

```
class Element {
  String name
  String title
  static constraints = {
    title nullable: true
  }
}
```

During creation String field trims automatically and empty string replaced by null

```
def e = new Element(name:'', title:'  sgg gg ')
assert e.name==null
assert e.title=='sgg gg'
```

I can't find this super feature in changelog of Grails & groovy. How I can disable it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From:  http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-Data-Binding-String-Trimming-And-Null-Conversions-td4645255.html

> The default behavior in Grails 2.3 is to trim strings during data binding.  In addition to that, another default behavior is to convert empty strings (strings with nothing in them, not even spaces) to null during data binding.  Those 2 things happen in that order so if you bind a String with nothing in it but spaces, the default behavior is to bind null because the String will be trimmed and then since it is empty it will be converted to null.  This is a sensible default.  There are separate config properties for disabling either of those behaviors.
>
> ```
>    // grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
>    grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull=false
>    grails.databinding.trimStrings=false
> ```

I believe it's mentioned [here in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding)